# What's the point of having <| in F#?

Tags: parameters, f#

In F# you have the backward pipe operator `<|`, which like its brother `|>` serves as a way to pass parameters into functions...

Now I already understand the great idea behind having `|>`, letting the programmer easily see the value affected rather than having to go through a chain of nested function calls is awesome and looks beautiful:

```
let newList = someList
                |> List.map (fun x -> x * 3)
                |> List.filter (fun x -> x > 12)
```

So my question is, if functions are called like `funcName param` anyway, what's the point of having `funcName <| param`?

I've also seen some write functions like this `func1 <| value |> func2` what exactly does that do?

Comment: it's not a duplicate though, I already see the point of pipes

Answer (score 6):

It exists to avoid parentheses, similarly to `$` in Haskell. See section *Function application with $* in [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions).

Comment: Notice that `$` is right-associative, while `<|` is left-associative.

Comment: What kind of impact would that make?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee The parser would read the code in a different order, so at best you'll get type-related errors, and at worst, the code will type-check then execute in a different order at run-time.

Comment: It's the difference between `raise (InvalidOperationException("Don't do that!"))` and `raise <| InvalidOperationException("Don't do that!")` In some cases a backwards pipe is less irritating than wrapping an entire expression in parens.